# Umbraco - Check if request is XmlHttpRequest

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest, umbraco

I'm doing an AJAX feature for my Umbraco website.

Basically what I'm trying to do is when someone requests for http://mysite.com/news with the XmlHttpRequest header then I want Umbraco to return JSON of the following page.

What I've been trying to do is finding the right place to check for the header in Umbraco. Basically I want to override or inherit some class where I could check the header and return the page in Json or HTML depending on the header.

I'm using Umbraco 4.7.0 (1.0.4090.21631)

Any feedback would be more than welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use the URL Rewriting module for IIS7 to detect the content-type in the request, then redirect to the same URL with /jsonTemplate on the end of it. You would then create a masterpage called jsonTemplate, with a single macro inside it, which would return your JSON.

This is common for Umbraco - specifying a separate template with a separate macro to return a different view of the same content. Check out http://blog4umbraco.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68424#1138733 for an example of an XSLT macro that returns RSS using this approach.

Comment: Thanks, I've been going quite blind doing it my own way, basically a HttpModule that checks the request header and returns the Umbraco page in JSON. What do you think of that idea?

Comment: I will mark your reply as the answer, as it is the closest one to my solution. I did go my own way by creating my own HttpModule and checking the header. Works like a charm :)

Comment: It's kinda the same thing. Suggest checking out the altTemplate approach - works great for RSS, JSON, etc. There's also /base which allows you to write .NET classes and methods, register them in /config/restExtensions.config, and then call them via URL with parameters - I commonly use this to return JSON myself, when not using the altTemplate method.

Comment: Okay cool thanks. With my module I can do Ajax request on a normal page, like mypage.com/news and get JSON object back with all the matadata alias/values. Very handy :-) Normal request returns the HTML of that page.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `Content-Type` header from server side logic. Your Javascript should be specifying a `Content-Type` like `application/json`.

Comment: Yeah I would do that, but I'm not sure where on the server-side. Basically I want to create a class library that overrides or inherits some of the Umbraco default behavior and does this server-side check. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you use something like traditional handler or WCF service inside your asp.net application? I've never used Umbraco, but just out of curiosity, would you recommend it? I'm looking to migrate off of a terrible CMS that I'm being forced to use, and Umbraco looked promising.

Comment: I ended up writing a HttpModule and subscribing to an event where I do all the checks.
I don't have much experience with Umbraco but with what I've experienced so far it's pretty good, open-source, etc. Can't really compare it since I haven't used any other .NET CMS.